# Replace string that doesn't match with other in R

Tags: r

I'm teaching myself how to use Shiny App in R and am using some example survey data. There are multiple response questions with the option for the responder to input "Other". I want to replace the custom input with "Other".

```
example <- data.frame(Response = 1:4, Question = c("Answer 1", "Answer 1, Answer 2", "custom input", "Answer 2, another custom input"))
```

I tried exacting any answer that didn't match one of the answers using `grep()` and `paste()`. Then replacing those values with `gsub()` but this only works if they didn't select multiple answers like Response 3. It doesn't work for Response 4.

```
example$Question_cleaned <- gsub(paste(grep("Answer 1|Answer 2", str_split(example$Question,", "), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE), collapse = "|"), "Other", example$Question)
```

For clarity this is my desired outcome:

```
desired_outcome <- data.frame(Response = 1:4, Question_cleaned = c("Answer 1", "Answer 1, Answer 2", "Other", "Answer 2, Other"))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are splitting the string you don't need to perform partial match using `grep`/`gsub`. Try this approach :

```
answers <- c('Answer 1', 'Answer 2')

example$Question_cleaned <- sapply(strsplit(example$Question, ',\\s*'), function(x) {
  x[!x %in% answers ] <- 'Other'
  toString(x)
})

example

#  Response                       Question   Question_cleaned
#1        1                       Answer 1           Answer 1
#2        2             Answer 1, Answer 2 Answer 1, Answer 2
#3        3                   custom input              Other
#4        4 Answer 2, another custom input    Answer 2, Other
```

Comment: This worked. However, I had to change NA values to "No Response" and include "No Response" as an answer. Otherwise, NA values would be labeled as Other. Thanks!